# Errors when added image_picker dependency for flutter (iOS)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I needed to use image_picker for my application. I added image_picker dependency onto my pubspec.yaml file, and for the iOS I have added    NSCameraUsageDescription
    NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
    NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
onto the info.plist file, but I get this error when trying to run the app on iOS simulator.

This is the error I got when trying to run the app.
`Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
/Users/sirapol/Desktop/FirstCareFrontEnd/care_now_frontend_v1/ios/Runner/Info.plist: Property List error: Found non-key inside
 at line 27 / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.
Running Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                            2.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/sirapol/Desktop/FirstCareFrontEnd/care_now_frontend_v1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycl
    e/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team
    ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')`

this is part of my pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  provider: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
  path_provider: ^1.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

This is my info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>care_now_frontend_v1</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have no idea why the error is happening. Because I have done this once and got no error. Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you try using the latest version of the image picker? :  image_picker: ^0.6.1+4

Comment: you need to add `<string>` after `<key>`

Comment: yes I have tried the new version of image_picker, still getting the same error

Comment: the problem seems to come from info.plist, which I tried adding <string> after <key> and does not solve the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be sure you have a value added after key values in plist files. Add string values under those keys and it should fix the problem.

Example:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to your phone's location</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access your photo library</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access your phone's camera</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow the app to record using your phone's microphone</string>
```

As for the architecture mapping errors try setting your iOS deployment target to 9.0 or above in the xcode project.

Also, I noticed you have a trailing  value in your code example, that looks like it should be moved to under

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error you are encountering is on xcode when builiding, then you can open your Podfile and add this

```
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
platform :ios, '9.0'
project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Hopefully this will solve the image_picker issue, It worked for me and i was able to publish

Answer (score -1):

In case someone else has this issue, if you add the keys at the end of the file it will fail and send the Xcode could not read the Info.plist file error, test it on Xcode version 12.

For example this file will work fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict>  
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>    
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>    
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>   
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>     
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>   
....
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>   
    <string>Share pictures</string>     
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>     
    <string>Share pictures</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

However if you move the keys to the end like this, it will fail:

```
....
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>   
        <string>Share pictures</string>     
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>     
        <string>Share pictures</string>
    <false/> 
    </dict> 
    </plist>
```

Comment: That latter example isn't a valid plist - you pasted the usage descriptions in between the `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>` and its `<false/>` (you should have pasted them after `<false/> ` and before `</dict>`). (I think the confusion arose from the lack of indentation on the last key in the first example).